# One button submits AJAX, another button queries result of that AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

This question is part of me trying to learn promises and deferreds. Suppose you have a button that submits a `POST`:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
  $.post({...})
})
```

My understanding is that AJAX is itself a promise (which makes obvious sense), so what I'd like to do is, when user clicks `#check`, it returns the output of the AJAX once it is complete (assuming that `#check` can and will always be clicked only after `#submit` has been clicked).

I thought this was simple enough, so my initial code was:

```
$("#check").click(function() {
  $.when($.post({...})).done( function(data) {
    console.log("data")
  })  
})
```

But I realize that in this implementation, the AJAX wouldn't start `POST`ing until `#check` is clicked. There's no need for any `#submit` button and having the AJAX `.post` in `#submit` is redundant.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm doing using promises/deferreds?

Comment: It's not really clear why you'd want two buttons to perform one AJAX request.  It seems like that's a timing problem waiting to happen.  Why not just append `.done()` to the initial AJAX call and specify there what you want to do with the response?

Comment: you may also consider preventing the default submit action, or your page may disappear before any ".done" is executed

Comment: because I ONLY want to act on the response once `#check` is pressed... how can I implement that?

Comment: Just as an FYI James, AJAX is not a promise, it is a mechanism for sending and receiving data asynchronously. Granted, it is arguably improved by wrapping it and returning a promise of the future data rather than using the conventional callback approach.

Comment: @rasmeister - jquery has for a long time returned a promise (of sorts, not quite promise/A+ spec, I call it a broken promise) from its "ajax" family of functions - so, no wrapping required

Comment: @james - so you actually want separate submit and check buttons?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. so on click of a button `submit`, i want to submit something via AJAX, but then i want to use the result of that AJAX ONLY LATER when button `check` is clicked. 2 assumptions that hold true: button `check` will ALWAYS be clicked, and ALWAYS after button `submit`

Comment: Fair enough @Jaromanda. Was considering the term AJAX to refer to just that not to the jQuery `ajax()` method in my comment.

Comment: sure, but the question has $.post $.when ... and of course the `jquery` tag :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Promise when the #submit button is pressed, and then use that to establish a handler for the #check button.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var requestPromise = $.post( "xxx", function(response) {
    // do something here
  })
  .fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
  })
  $("#check").click(function() {
    requestPromise.done(function(response) {
      // do something meaningful with response here, or other logic
    });
    // disable #check button and remove click handler here
  }
  // enable #check button here
})
```

EDIT - as requested by OP

Here's the version using a compliant Promise:

```
    $("#submit").click(function() {
      var requestPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.post( "xxx", function(response) {
          // do something here
          resolve(response);
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
           alert( "error" );
           reject(response);
        });
      });
      $("#check").click(function() {
        requestPromise.then(function(response) {
          // do something meaningful with response here, or other logic
        });
        // disable #check button and remove click handler here
      }
      // enable #check button here
    })
```

Comment: jquery ajax functions return a promise, avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: I am assuming the #check button is disabled (that is why at the end of the #submit click they enable it, and yes, if they are using jQuery ajax() call, then they can use the psuedo-promise from that. The logic basically stays the same except no need to create a new Promise.

Comment: ahh, yes, I see that part of the question now that #check can only ever be clicked after #submit - pays to read the question :p

Comment: so i thought about this solution as well, but that point of the Promise constructor around a "promise" was bugging me... but if this is the way to go... i'll test it out

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a way of using the jQuery post() response as a pseudo-promise. It is disappointing that it isn't a compliant promise, but it will serve in this situation.

Comment: ok that makes much more sense to me (probably because i'm still not too sure about promises in the first place), and the entire simplicity of this answer and my inability to come up with it has been frustrating ugh... why is this such a mindbender

Comment: @rasmeister i don't know how easy this is for you (i don't know if you can see your own edits or not), but if it's easy, can you post the original more pure way of doing it and then the pseudo-way back-to-back? I just did a super quick check and this is working, but i want to come back tonight and sit with it a bit longer with some other examples to practice. many thanks for the help!

Comment: Asynchronous coding does take some time to get used to, but it is important in JavaScript land to understand it and be comfortable with it, so you are doing the right thing by diving into it.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this "pseudo-promise" vs "compliant promise" talk. jQuery promises pre-dates the standard, but work perfectly fine for what the OP is looking for. Creating a special ES6 promise does nothing but introduce a dependency on newer browsers. And in fact, jQuery 3 is Promises/A+ compliant. If you're using jQuery, use jQuery promises. If you're using Angular 1.x, use $q. If you use neither, use `Promise`. They all do the same in principle.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the promise returned by `post`.

```
var myPromise = null;
$("#submit").click( function() {
  myPromise = $.post({...});
});

$("#check").click(function() {
  if (myPromise) {
    myPromise.then( function(data) {
      console.log("data");
    });
  }
});
```

The other changes I made are using `then()` instead of `done()` (a single function to accept success, failure or progress) and I added statement-ending semicolons (because automatic semicolon insertion kills puppies).

And once you're done studying promises, move on swiftly to [observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/). With JavaScript the fun never stops.

Comment: I don't believe $.post return has a 'then()'. Could use done() or always()?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment on the question:

> i want to submit something via AJAX, but then i want to use the result of that AJAX ONLY LATER when button check is clicked.

You may be overcomplicating this.  You don't really need to dissect the AJAX request/promise/etc. between these two buttons.  Simply make the request in the first button and store the result, then use the result in the second button.  Something as simple as this:

```
// disable the check button until there is a result to check
$('#check').prop('disabled', true);

var ajaxResult;

$("#submit").click( function() {
    $.post({...})
     .done(function (result) {
         // any other logic you want to put here, then...
         ajaxResult = result;
         $('#check').prop('disabled', false);
     });
})

$('#check').click(function() {
    // the result is in ajaxResult, use it as needed here
});
```

Basically the "check" button doesn't have anything to do with AJAX.  It's just performing an action on data which exists in memory.  That button is simply enabled when that data is successfully fetched.

Comment: yes but the problem is i want the user to be able to hit `#check` when there ISN'T a result to check, and then wait until that result is available